# How do I fix an onclick that isn't working when I import a JavaScript function into my HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am doing it on pythonanywhere, and check for errors on the console of the inspect tool

I have a button formatted like the one below, but when ever I try and click it, it says that the function is undefined; even though I have it imported correctly.

The button is formatted like this:

```
<button type="button" id="ManualGain" class="buttons" onclick="IncreaseBal()">Press me for money</button>
```

The import is formatted like this:

```
<script type="text/html" src="GameCode.js"></script>
```

And here is the IncreaseBal function in GameCode.js:

```
function IncreaseBal() {
   GameVars.balance += 10
   document.getElementById("Balance").innerText = "Balance: " + GameVars.balance
}
```

The GameVar function is pretty much formatted as:

```
var GameVars = {
   balance = 0,
   ...
}
```

However, I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: use F12 developer tools, network tab to verify the script is being loaded without error

Comment: Your object structure is invalid, too. Should be `balance: 0`

Comment: It looks like type issue, you need to change `<script type="text/html"` to `<script type="text/javascript`

Comment: A listener is not a handler. Telling OP to use _"an event handler"_ when OP is already doing that is just confusing. And yes, inline event handlers(!) are not best practice but will do the job. Unobtrusive JS, and therefor, `.addEventListener()` would be the better option - but it's not relevant for the problem nor does it change the event handler into a listener.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> <script type="text/html" src="GameCode.js"></script>
> ```

You are using the `type` attribute to tell the browser to expect an HTML document when it requests the URL in the `src` attribute. HTML documents are not JavaScript programs. Since the browser doesn't know what to do with a `<script>` written in HTML, it doesn't do anything with it.

**Omit the `type` attribute** for regular JavaScript programs.

You *can* say `type="text/javascript"` but this only introduces the possibility of making an error.

You should use `type="module"` if your script is loading a JavaScript module (which doesn't appear to be the case here).

---

If you had used [this validator](https://validator.nu/) it would have spotted the error for you:

> Error: A script element with a src attribute must not have a type attribute whose value is anything other than the empty string, a JavaScript MIME type, or module.

---

Since the script isn't loading at present, it won't be triggering an error on your developer tools console yet but:

> ```
> var GameVars = {
>    balance = 0,
> ```

Object literal syntax uses `name: value` not `name = value`.

---

*Aside*

> ```
> function IncreaseBal() {
> var GameVars = {
> ```

Note that idiomatic JavaScript reserves variable names starting with capital letters for *classes* and *constructor functions* (i.e. things designed to be used with the `new` keyword). You shouldn't use that naming convention for regular functions and objects.

---

*Aside*

Intrinsic event attributes come with a host of issues, including some very unexpected scoping rules. Best practise is to avoid them in favour of [binding event listeners using JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener).

Comment: When I tried editing (or removing) the text/html type to anything else, it gives me a 404 error on the file and doesn't allow me to do anything. What would you recommend doing in this situation?

Comment: Using the correct URL to the JS. (If you say it is HTML then the browser won't even try to download it because it knows it can't process HTML as a script. If solving that problem gives you a 404 then your URL is wrong too.)